# Seleccionar solamente algunos commits de una rama para mergearlos en master

Tags: git

Quiero entregar un paquete de código para que puedan agregar funcionalidades. Necesito mantener intacto mi código inicial y en algún momento seleccionar solamente algunos commits realizados en el branch A para que sean mergeados en master. Les copio un esquema:

```
Master -------------------------------
              |                | >> en este paso quiero seleccionar qué mergear a máster
Branch A       ----------------
                   |       |
Branch B            -------
```

Answer (score 1):

`git cherry-pick <SHA-1>` fue diseñado especificamente para dicha tarea, para usarlo simplemente debes usarlo.

---

**Paso 1.**
Obtener el id del commit

`git log` o `git log --oneline`

---

**Paso 2**
Cambiar de rama, situarse en la rama en la cual quieres mezclar.

`git checkout <rama>`

---

**Paso 3** Usar cherry pick

`git cherry-pick <SHA-1>`

donde SHA-1 es el `id` de tu commit.